# unorderable types : str() > int()

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to read an excel file from python 3. while iterating through rows, when i compare with == sign there is no problem. But when i compare with > sign i am getting errors.

I saw some answers in this website and tried including int(). but its not working.

```
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(r"c:\censuspopdata.xlsx")
print (wb.sheetnames)
ws = wb.active
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Population by Census Tract')
tuple(sheet['A1':'C3'])

for rowOfCellObjects in sheet['A1':'D24']:

    for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:

    if cellObj.value > 10766:

        print(cellObj.coordinate,cellObj.value)
print('---END OF ROW---')
```

I face problem in the following line
  if cellObj.value > 10766:

when i run this i get "unorderable types: str() > int().

I understand the problem but don't know what is wrong with this code.  Can anyone guide me

Comment: You already mentioned trying to cast `cellObj.value` to an integer. Could it be that you're trying to compare empty cells, and `openpyxl` tries to parse those as a string? How about adding a `try/except` block, and if the cell is not empty, and can be casted to an integer, then you compare to `10766`.

Comment: HI, thanks for your answer.  The cells are not empty in the excel sheet. There are 4 cells in each row. 2 cells integer and 2 cells string. The problem persists . can you help me

Comment: From your other comment, it seems that for some reason, you're trying to convert `"CensusTract"` to an integer, so that's why it fails. You should print out your cells before converting them to int() and comparing, to check what it is that you're picking up. Could it be that you're reading headers of the data, that `openpyxl` structures the cells somewhat differently than you'd expect, or that it opens the wrong Sheet?

Comment: Also, and keep this in mind for future questions as well, a small sample of the data would be valuable in getting an immediate answers, without us trying to guess what's the content of the Excel file and why it produces that error.